# Gurobi and C++- How it works together using Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, gurobi

First of all I am complete new to C++, so if you know the answer please be patient with me ;). Here my problem:
I wanna solve an IP with Gurobi in a C++ Code. The Code itself seems fine since there are no expression marked as errors. However when I run the Code I get the following error report:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

and many lines like that:

```
"GRBLinExpr::GRBLinExpr(GRBVar, double)", referenced from: 
bridge_problem::max_flow_lp(time_expanded_network&, lemon::ListDigraph&, lemon::DigraphExtender<lemon::ListDigraphBase>::ArcMap<int>&, lemon::DigraphExtender<lemon::ListDigraphBase>::ArcMap<int>&, lemon::DigraphExtender<lemon::ListDigraphBase>::NodeMap<int>&) in bridge_problem.cpp.o
```

I suppose that the mistake is in my CMakeList.txt file. This file was automatically created since I am using Clion and for including gurobi I entered those additional lines:

```
include_directories(/Library/gurobi604/mac64/include) 
link_directories(/Library/gurobi604/mac64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a) 
link_directories(/Library/gurobi604/mac64/lib/libgurobi60.so)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need any more information just let me know. (In case it is important I using a mac).

EDIT: I changed my make code since I found this one:
https://github.com/joschu/trajopt/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindGUROBI.cmake
I changed the version since I have gurobi604 but it still does not work. My new error message is:

```
fatal error: 'gurobi_c++.h' file not found #include "gurobi_c++.h"
```

I don't get it since I thought by

```
find_path(GUROBI_INCLUDE_DIR
      NAMES gurobi_c++.h
      PATHS "$ENV{GUROBI_HOME}/include"
              "/Library/gurobi604/mac64/include"
             "C:\\libs\\gurobi604\\include"
      )
```

that should be easy to find. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is here nobody who can help me? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

From the small excerpt of your CMakeLists.txt, I expect you should be using [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html) rather than `link_directories`.

I'd normally recommend linking to the static version of any library rather than the shared if possible (i.e. in this case prefer "libgurobi_c++.a" over "libgurobi60.so" assuming they're the same library, just compiled differently).

So, if your exe is called `MyExe`, you could do:

```
target_link_libraries(MyExe /Library/gurobi604/mac64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a)
```

Also, it's almost always best to avoid specifying hard-coded paths in your CMakeLists.txt.  Although *your* copy of "libgurobi_c++.a" lives in "/Library/gurobi604/mac64/lib/", that won't be the case for other users, or on different platforms.

You can avoid this by having CMake "find" the library, for example by calling [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_library.html):

```
find_library(Gurobi NAMES gurobi_c++)
if(NOT Gurobi)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find Gurobi lib.  Try setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH")
endif()
target_link_libraries(MyExe ${Gurobi})
```

Then, when you run CMake, you just need to tell it where the Gurobi library is.  I'm not sure how you do that in CLion, but for example if you were running CMake from the command line, you'd do:

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Library/gurobi604/mac64
```

Comment: Thanks Fraser, 
I changed the code as you suggested: 

    find_library(Gurobi NAMES gurobi_c++ )
    if(NOT Gurobi)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find Gurobi lib.  Try setting     CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH")
    endif()
    include_directories(${Gurobi})
    target_link_libraries(MyProjekt ${Gurobi})

Now I get the new error:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (message):
  Failed to find Gurobi lib.  Try setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Comment: I try to set a CMAKE_Prefix_path by CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH(/Library/gurobi604/mac64) at the beginning but apperently CMAKE_PREFIX... is an unknown command. I think for clion I don't have to call cmake . since i just running by pressing a button. So I wasn't sure where to enter the Prefix path.